# There are a better place for put our load tags?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a .html with some tags that is used in a auth system.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% block title %} <title>Sign In</title> {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
        <h1>Sign in</h1>

        {% load socialaccount %} <!-- Loading -->

        <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google'%}">Login with google</a>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

But this way isn't good for readability.

I want to know if there are better places to put the load templates into. Because this way the readability is predicated.

Comment: At the top of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django, the ***{% load %}*** tag is typically placed at the top of the file for better readability. This makes it clear which libraries are being used in the template. Here’s how you can restructure your HTML:

```
{% load socialaccount %} <!-- Loading at the top -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% block title %} <title>Sign In</title> {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
        <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google'%}">Login with google</a>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

This way, anyone reading the code will immediately know that the **socialaccount library** is being used in this template. It’s a small change, but it can make a big difference in readability!